# recovering data from an "lm" object in R?

Tags: r

I was wondering if there might be a way to ***re-obtain (recover)*** the data for `jen` from the output of `lm` object in R *assuming we don't know what is the name of the person but only the role of `jen` as the predictor?*

In other words, how to re-obtain, predictor data from an `lm` object?

**Here is the data:**

```
q = data.frame(bob = 1:5 - 3, jen = c(1.7, 2.6, 2.5, 4.4, 3.8) - 3)
m <- lm(bob ~ jen, q)
```

**Here is what I have tried with no success:**

```
eval(names(m$coefficients)[2])
```

Comment: Without being so tricky, you can get the name of the predictor like `labels(terms(m))` - and then to build on the existing answer - `m[["model"]][labels(terms(m))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
m$model[, 2]
# [1] -1.3 -0.4 -0.5  1.4  0.8
```

or, if you want to see the name as well,

```
m$model[, 2, drop = FALSE]
#    jen
# 1 -1.3
# 2 -0.4
# 3 -0.5
# 4  1.4
# 5  0.8
```

or

```
q[[names(m$model)[2]]]
# [1] -1.3 -0.4 -0.5  1.4  0.8
q[, names(m$model)[2]]
# [1] -1.3 -0.4 -0.5  1.4  0.8
q[, 2]
# [1] -1.3 -0.4 -0.5  1.4  0.8
q[[2]]
# [1] -1.3 -0.4 -0.5  1.4  0.8
q[, names(m$model)[2], drop = FALSE]
#    jen
# 1 -1.3
# 2 -0.4
# 3 -0.5
# 4  1.4
# 5  0.8
q[, 2, drop = FALSE]
#    jen
# 1 -1.3
# 2 -0.4
# 3 -0.5
# 4  1.4
# 5  0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use `augment` from [broom](/questions/tagged/broom) to provide you with tidied contents of the model.

```
q <- data.frame(bob = 1:5 - 3, jen = c(1.7, 2.6, 2.5, 4.4, 3.8) - 3)
m <- lm(bob ~ jen, q)

broom::augment(m)

#   bob  jen    .fitted   .se.fit     .resid      .hat    .sigma    .cooksd .std.resid
# 1  -2 -1.3 -1.6595745 0.6607174 -0.3404255 0.5595745 1.0191405 0.21426617 -0.5807632
# 2  -1 -0.4 -0.5106383 0.4273013 -0.4893617 0.2340426 1.0069205 0.06122685 -0.6330542
# 3   0 -0.5 -0.6382979 0.4444382  0.6382979 0.2531915 0.9473309 0.11854243  0.8362420
# 4   1  1.4  1.7872340 0.6938041 -0.7872340 0.6170213 0.6009252 1.67091751 -1.4402230
# 5   2  0.8  1.0212766 0.5121137  0.9787234 0.3361702 0.6698641 0.46834095  1.3600185
```

This could also be subset to return only the values for `jen`.

```
broom::augment(m)$jen

# [1] -1.3 -0.4 -0.5  1.4  0.8
```